# Userscript won't un-focus the text input on some pages

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a small Greasemonkey script which is meant to unfocus everything and just return the focus to the top level of the webpage.
The code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 32) {
        document.activeElement.blur()
    }
}, true);
```

It works fine on all the web pages I use, except for *WhatsApp Web*. It immediately refocuses the message typing box.
I have turned autofocus off in Firefox.

How can one ensure that truly nothing is left in focus? Not even the WhatsApp Web message input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any errors or messages in the browser console?  And what browser version are you using?

Anyway, without creating a WhatsApp account, or you posting an MCVE, here *some* possibilities:

- The page uses JS to reset focus -- triggered by `keydown`.
- The page uses JS to reset focus -- triggered by something else.
- The page has reset the default active element ( (Used to be) possible on some browsers).
- The page has overridden `document.activeElement.blur()`

This code might work:

```
document.addEventListener ('keydown', zEvent => {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey && zEvent.keyCode === 32) {
        let actElem     = document.activeElement;
        if (actElem)    actElem.blur ();
        else            console.error ("document.activeElement is unset");

        zEvent.preventDefault ();
        zEvent.stopImmediatePropagation ();
    }
}, true);
```

If it doesn't and there are no relevant messages in the browser console, run this from the console:

```
console.log (document.activeElement.blur.toSource() );
```

And see if it's not the native function.

Another thing you can try is to find or create a different input and `.focus()` it. (`document.body.focus()` will often not work, alas.)

---

Otherwise, you'll have to find the javascript that's resetting focus and block that.  How to do such a thing depends on exactly what the page code is. It's something for a different question but various mechanisms have all been covered on other Stack Overflow questions already.

Comment: There are no errors. And I use the latest version of Firefox. After logging the active element, it seems like it is changed to body using blur(), but then it is automatically reset by the website it self. I will see if I can block this somehow. Thank you for your answer.